# Get exact file by extension type c#

Tags: c#

I am having a little trouble getting files into a string[].  Everything seems to be ok until I have a .docx and doc file and a .xlsx and a .xls file in my directory that I am searching.  Can someone advise me on how to acheive this?

Please see my code that I have so far below:

```
Filter = ".DOC|.DOCX|.XLS|.XLSX|.PDF|.TXT|.TIF|.TIFF"

public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter)
{
    // ArrayList will hold all file names
    System.Collections.ArrayList alFiles = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    // Create an array of filter string
    string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');

    // for each filter find mathing file names
    foreach (string FileFilter in MultipleFilters)
    {
        // add found file names to array list
        alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, FileFilter));
    }

    // returns string array of relevant file names
    return (string[])alFiles.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Thanks, 
George

Comment: "Everything seems to be ok until..."  What happens then? How is it different? What issue are you running into with those extensions?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, the above code places duplicates of the file in the array, if the file in the directory contains a .docx and .xlsx file in it.

Comment: It has duplicates, cause you said so. Once got a collection, remove from it files that you are *not* concern about (duplicates)

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ [Distinct(TSource)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of LINQ's [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (***System.Linq***).

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

```
Filter = ".DOC|.DOCX|.XLS|.XLSX|.PDF|.TXT|.TIF|.TIFF";

public string[] GetFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter)
{
     List<string> alFiles = new List<string>();

     string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');

     foreach (string FileFilter in MultipleFilters)
     {
         alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, FileFilter));
     }

     return alFiles.Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Notice that I am now creating a new `List<string>` instance (***System.Collections.Generic***), instead of your `ArrayList`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried that but I am still getting duplicates into my list, for instance this filename exists in position 0 and 1 "230615143000_1.docx"

Comment: No luck Mati,  I am still getting duplicates of the docx file.

Comment: Apologies Mati - Ignore me your first suggestion worked and I was being silly.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou It's no problem at all, I am glad it worked!

Comment: @MatiCicero @GeorgeGeorgiou I would use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a List, for speed improvements, we don't know how many files will be there. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the code as originally posted doesn't return **any** files, because none of the calls to `Directory.GetFiles()` include a wildcard in the filter.

Second, assuming that the original filter did include wildcards, there's a nasty little surprise in the MSDN [Directory.GetFiles(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern such
>   as "*.txt", the number of characters in the specified extension
>   affects the search as follows:
>
> •If the specified extension is exactly three characters long, the
>   method returns files with extensions that **begin with** the specified
>   extension. For example, "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" **and**
>   "book.xlsx".
>
> •In all other cases, the method returns files that **exactly** match the
>   specified extension. For example, "*.ai" returns "file.ai" but not
>   "file.aif".

(emphasis added)

Rather than trying to work around the "helpful" behavior of the `Directory.GetFiles(string, string)` overload, I'd use the `Directory.GetFiles(string)` overload to get all the files and then filter the results using LINQ:

```
public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter)
{
    string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');

    var SelectedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder)
        .Where(f => MultipleFilters.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpper()))
        .Select(f => f);

    return SelectedFiles.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are huge number of files in the folder then getting all files could cause memory problem.
In below code I am searching files based on wild card filter and then filtering them using LINQ :)

```
string Filter = ".DOC|.DOCX|.XLS|.XLSX|.PDF|.TXT|.TIF|.TIFF" //without "*"
public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter)
{
    var filters = Filter.ToUpper().Split('|');
    return filters.SelectMany(filter => System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, "*"+filter)).Where(file=> filters.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper())).ToArray();
}
```